# How to get display name for NSLocale in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, localization, nsbundle, nslocale

I have the following problem:

I have a NSLocale object and want to access a resource in a .lproj directory for this locale.
For this to work I need to full name of the locale, for example "German". I can't find a way to get this string from a NSLocale object.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind:

```
NSLocale *locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:language] autorelease];
[locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleIdentifier value:language]);
```